# I want a testforblock command to tell if a chest is empty

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to test if there are items in a chest, but how would I test if there are no items in a chest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `List:[]` to check for an empty list, so you can do the following:

```
/testforblock X Y Z chest * {Items:[]}
```